# How to stop GL_Points from removing lines created by GL_line_loop

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, polygon

I am working on a program that is supposed to allow the user to create a polygon, and then specify random points for the program to check if they are inside the polygon or not.

```
GLint vert[100][2];
int width = 400, height = 600, n = 0, type = GL_LINE_STRIP, v;
bool rubberbanding = false;

void display(){
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     if(n == 1 && (type == GL_LINE_STRIP)){
          glBegin(GL_POINTS);
          glVertex2iv(vert[0]);
          glEnd();
     }
     glBegin(type);
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             glVertex2iv(vert[i]);
     }
     glEnd();
     glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I am having trouble with this next part here. The user creates lines with GL_LINE_STRIP, and then they are supposed to click 'c' to close the polygon. However after they close the polygon I want them to be able specify random points. But when I switch the type to GL_POINTS it removes all the lines, and I am left with points at the vertices.

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
     switch(key){
                 case 'r': n = 0; type = GL_LINE_STRIP;  break;

                 case 'c': type = GL_LINE_LOOP; break;
                 //case 'v': type = GL_POINTS; break;
     }
     // type = GL_POINTS;
     glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

How can I fix this so that after the user closes the polygon, they can create points without the polygon disappearing?

Edit: This is the code for the button click:

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
     switch(button){
     case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
                         if(state == GLUT_DOWN){
                                  v = n++;
                                  vert[v][0] = x;
                                  vert[v][1] = height - 1 - y;
                                  rubberbanding = true;
                                  glutPostRedisplay();
                         }
                         else{
                                  rubberbanding = false;
                         }
                         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your lines are disappearing because your changing the primitive type from `GL_LINE_STRIP` or `GL_LINE_LOOP` to `GL_POINTS`. You need to draw your polygon with `GL_LINE_*`, THEN draw the points with `GL_POINTS`.

Comment: You want to draw lines and you want to draw points. So you need 2 loops and 2 different primitive types. First draw the lines in one loop and than draw the points in another loop.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I have to create the two loops in the button click function?

Comment: @3Dave I am not sure what GL_LINE_* is .. it keeps saying that its undefined

Comment: It's shorthand for `GL_LINE_STRIP` or `GL_LINE_LOOP` - whichever you want to use. It is not literal code.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to implement the two loops?

Comment: *"So what you are saying is that I have to create the two loops in the button click function?"* - NO. 2 loops  in the `draw` function. The `keyboard` function changes the control variables of the loops (it activates or deactivates the drawing by conditions which are stored to variables) and it may change the primitive type for the lines (`GL_LINE_STRIP` -> `GL_LINE_LOOP`). The 2nd loop always draws `GL_POINTS`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Im sorry, Im still not getting it. So with regards to my functions, the 'draw' function is my display function correct? And in there I am supposed create another loop that allows me to draw points

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to do the following:

Create a display function, which can draw lines and points. The lines are stored in the array of vertices starting with index 0 and ending at index `m-1`.
The points are stored in the array of vertices, too. The start at index `m` and end at index  `n-1`.
The lines are drawn using the primitive type  `GL_LINE_STRIP`. If the line is closed then the primitive type `GL_LINE_LOOP` is used.
The points are drawn using `GL_POINTS`.

```
GLint vert[100][2];
int n = 0, m = 0;
bool closed = false;

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(closed ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        glVertex2iv(vert[i]);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(int i = m; i < n; i++)
        glVertex2iv(vert[i]);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

In the `keybord` function, the states are changed:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
        case 'r': n = 0; m = 0; closed = false; break;
        case 'c': closed = true; break;
    }
}
```

The `mouse` function adds a vertex coordinate to the container and increments `n` and/or `m` with respect to the state `closed`.

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    switch(button)
    {
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if( state == GLUT_DOWN )
            {
                if ( n < 100 )
                {
                    vert[n][0] = x;
                    vert[n][1] = height - 1 - y;
                    n ++;
                    if ( !closed )
                        m = n;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

---

When a [glVertex](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) is called then the color which was set by [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml). OpenGL is a state a engine. If a state is changed it is kept until it is changed again, even beyond frames.

If you want to draw the lines in one color, but the point in another color, than you have to set the colors before the loops which draw the lines and points:

```
glColor3f(1,1,1);
glBegin(closed ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_LINE_STRIP);
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    glVertex2iv(vert[i]);
glEnd();

glColor3f(1,0,0);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for(int i = m; i < n; i++)
    glVertex2iv(vert[i]);
glEnd();
```

---

Even rubber banding can be implemented with ease. Implement the [`glutPassiveMotionFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html) callback and store the current mouse position:

```
int mx = 0, my = 0;    

void mousemove(int x, int y)
{
    mx = x;
    my = height - 1 - y;
}
```

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mousemove);
```

Add a final vertex coordinate to the current mouse position when you draw the line, dependent on the state of drawing:

```
glBegin(closed ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_LINE_STRIP);
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    glVertex2iv(vert[i]);
if (n>0 && !closed)
    glVertex2i(mx, my);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful. I played around with the code for a bit, and I was able to figure it out. One question I had was with this line:     'glBegin(closed ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_LINE_STRIP);'
Im not really sure what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Also I was wondering how I could keep the color of the polygon the same but change the color of the points. I tried this:
  `glBegin(GL_POINTS);
          glColor3f(1,0,0);
  for (int i = m; i < n; i++) {
   glVertex2iv(vert[i]);
  }
  glEnd();`
But it turned everything red. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: @jmac See the extension to the answer.

Comment: I apologize for asking so much, but I could really use your help with [another question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365014/determining-if-a-point-is-inside-a-2d-polygon-specified-by-the-user-opengl). If you could check it out I would really appreciate it. It relates to this question, and it is for an assignment that is due tomorrow.